# SUNION wrong result order

Tags: redis

I have two sets "set1" and "set2" and just want to append elements from "set2" (not presented in "set1") to "set1"
I wanted to use redis's SUNIUON, but it returns elements in very strange order

```
redis> SADD key1 "a"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key1 "b"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key1 "c"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key2 "c"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key2 "d"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key2 "e"
(integer) 1
redis> SUNION key1 key2
1) "b"
2) "c"
3) "d"
4) "a"
5) "e"
redis>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal since *Redis Sets are an **unordered** collection of Strings*: see the [official documentation](http://redis.io/topics/data-types).

Comment: Once again, sets keep track of unique elements, in an unordered fashion. You say that `SADD` keeps order, but that's wrong:
    `redis> SADD key1 a
    (integer) 1
    redis> SADD key1 b
    (integer) 1
    redis> SADD key1 c
    (integer) 1
    redis> SMEMBERS key1
    1) "c"
    2) "a"
    3) "b"`

You should probably use another data type that better fit your purpose.